# Xcode 4 not using new builds

Tags: build, xcode4

I've been using Xcode 4 for the last two weeks now, and I'm a little frustrated having to do a clean (shft+cmd+K) every time I change a single line of code before building (cmd+B) and running (cmd+R) again.

In previous versions of Xcode, rebuilding was enough for the simulator to use the latest build.

Am I doing it wrong? A lot of things have really improved but I can't get the hang of this "build and run flow".

Comment: Some clarification might help us help you: Have you modified any settings in the active scheme? Do you have more than one scheme for the executable you're trying to run in the simulator? Have you changed anything under the target's Build Settings tab?

Comment: If I look to my active scheme, the build section has one target, and under it my dependent static library targets (separate projects). The target's build settings have some custom ones, but none of which I'd say would influence the building of my dependencies.

Comment: How about your build settings? Any of the bolded (customized) settings stand out as "odd?"

Comment: Nope. The ones customized are archs, baseSDK, validate built product, code sign. ident., comp version (llvm2.0), strip debug symbols, depl target, other linker flags, header search paths, optimiz. level, some llvm ones and a user defined "PREBINDING" set to "NO".

Comment: Anything special about your intermediate build folder? Did you set a custom location in the project settings or in Xcode's preferences? Maybe to a folder that gets synchronized?

Comment: The locations are the default (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData). I actually do have a second scheme building the same target but it's settings are the same. I'm gonna play with it a bit at home, but if you should still have any ideas, please share them.

Comment: To give an update, still no success in rebuilding without cleaning.

Comment: But to give a bit more information, my project structure is an iOS app with 3 static libraries as direct dependencies. Each dependency depends on one of the other, but they are only dependent on each other in the application project (where they're also linked with). When I look in my scheme build section, I see that all actions of the main project are checked. The dependencies have no actions, but when I add them as separate targets (with all actions checked), it still doesn't work the way I expect.

Comment: Another thing, when I look at the build log, I see any changed source files are correctly recompiled, added resources copied, ... It looks like it just isn't copied to the simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are your library files appearing in red (missing)?

Build the project once for your iOS device, then add the .a to the Link Binary With Libraries again. Now the .a will appear as normal (not red - missing).

Now every time you build/run the project in the simulator, the libraries/subprojects will be build too.

I've had the same problem.

Comment: They were indeed missing. Building and relinking made it working correctly now. Thank you very much! (Also many thanks to Joshua)

Comment: This tip is the only thing that worked for me to get my static library automatically recompiling when I run the main project.  I wish I could upvote this 5 times. Thank you!